# Hidden input has a value but it's always null in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Working on mvc5 app. In my ajax form I have alot of fields, including one hidden input...

```
 <input id="currentView" name="currentView" 
      value="calendar" type="hidden" />
```

Whenever I post to my action, currentView is null, unless I change type to "text". Then I get the value fine.

The beginning of the action is defined as...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetEvents(string userName, string currentView, 
           string theStatus)
    {
```

The other params are in the Model and come across fine. Is this the issue? Does currentView have to be in the Model for the hidden field to work? I guess I'm just confused as to why when I change the type to text it works. My understanding was that as long as I have a name defined it's accessible in the request vars.

Thanks!

**** UPDATE: Here's the top portion of my Ajax form *****

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
         new AjaxOptions
          {
              HttpMethod = "POST",
              Url = "/Scheduler/GetEvents",
              UpdateTargetId = "mainTable"
           }))
           {
              @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
              @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
              <input id="currentView" name="currentView" 
                   value="calendar" type="text" 
                   style="display: none;" />
```

As you can see I hacked it by using display: none. When I change type to "hidden" it doesn't work.

Comment: What you are doing seems ok to me. ModelBinder uses name property to bind the data so your understanding is right. You using Ajax.BeginForm right?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you give us more details like whole Html ?

Comment: @User3250 yes. I updated it up above. Thanks

Comment: yeah there is no issue , currentView doesnt need to be in the model for the hidden field to work.  so to debug your issue, if you provide full html code, then it will helpful for us.

Comment: @KarthikElumalai thanks. My client wouldn't like me to do that. And, the cshtml is very extensive, involving partial views, etc... So, I can't post it in it's entirety. But, the confusing thing is that I change the type and it either works or doesn't work. Hmmmm.... :-(

Comment: @WebDevGuy2  it works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

instead of sending value with hidden field you can try sending it in route values like this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEvents", "Scheduler", new { currentView ="calander"},
                                        new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                             HttpMethod = "POST",
                                             UpdateTargetId = "mainTable"
                                        }))
{
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative way. I'm still confused though as to why the hidden field doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 try changing the name and id of the field

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 you can also try `@Html.Hidden("currentView", "calander")`